# Laravel 5.8 Dynamic Dependant Select Dropdowns

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to get subcategories of current category using JQuery Ajax for creating posts.
It doesn't work for me but when i change the URL on browser like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/back/posts/create/json-subcategories?category_id=1 it brings all subcategory in an array

[here's an image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GeJU.png)

**Route Page:**

```
Route::get('/posts/create', ['uses'=>'Admin\PostController@create','as'=>'post-create', 'middleware'=> 'permission:Post List|All'] );

Route::get('/posts/create/json-subcategories', ['uses'=>'Admin\PostController@subcategories','as'=>'post-create', 'middleware'=> 'permission:Post List|All'] );
```

**PostController:**

```
 public function create()
    {
         $page_name = 'Create Post';
        $categories = Category::where('status',1)->pluck('name','id'); 
        return view('admin.post.create',compact('page_name','categories'));
    }



public function subcategories()
    {

       $category_id = Input::get('category_id');
      $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id', '=', $category_id)->get();
      return response()->json($subcategories);
    }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Your Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="categories" id="categories">
              <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Category ===</option>
                @foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
                  <option value="{{$value}}">{{ $value }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Your Subcategory</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="subcategories" id="subcategories">
              <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Subcategory ===</option>
            </select>
          </div>



<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#categories').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

  var category_id = e.target.value;
        $.get('/posts/create/json-subcategories?category_id=' + category_id,function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      $('#subcategories').empty();
          $('#subcategories').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Subcategory ===</option>');

$.each(data, function(index, subcategoriesObj){
            $('#subcategories').append('<option value="'+ subcategoriesObj.id +'">'+ subcategoriesObj.name +'</option>');
          })

    });

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is your URL example prefixed with `/back`? Because your route file is not showing this behavior. Maybe the error is to find in this construction but there is also another reason.

For me, your problem looks like you are not setting your keys correctly. The `pluck()` method on a collection returns all values of a given key as described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck

Because that you pass the `id`-key as well into the `pluck`-method all the values of the `name`-key will be keyed with the value of the respective `id` of the record.

So your view should probably look like this (not tested):

```php
...
<select class="form-control" name="categories" id="categories">
    <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Category ===</option> 
         @foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
             // changed the value of the value-attribute to the key of the passed collection
             <option value="{{$key}}">{{ $value }}</option>
         @endforeach
</select>
...
```

**BUT**:
because I assume your `subcategory`-entity isn't only used for your `category` but rather a mostly independent entity, maybe you can think about these following points:

> - You can also make use of Laravels Resource feature.
>     https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers
> - the route to receive the `subcategory`, even for a specific parent key, shouldn't live within the create route of your category. It's an independent table and datatype so you can give it a route like:

```php
Route::get('/category/subcategories/{category}', 'CategoryContoller@getSubcategories');
```

As you can see in the previous example, I added a route parameter (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters) which gives you the ability to invoke a model directly from a route.
Also plausible would be to say, this request has to do with `subcategory` entity so it will be handled within a `SubcategoryController`. But while this is always a thing of personal preference it's also for me more plausible to use it this way because we will receive the subcategories from the category itself later on. And so we will invoke and handle the `category`-model in its own controller which feels better to me.

To use this approach you have to change/ add 2 things:

> - Set up the route model binding (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) in the `boot`-method of your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); // kept this line if its there, add it if not

    Route::model('category', App\Category::class); // add this new line
}
```

> - Add relations to you models:

```php
# Category
public function subcategories() {
    $this->hasMany(App\Subcategory::class);
}
```

```php
# Subcatgory
public function category() {
    $this->belongsTo(App\Category::class);
}
```

After that, you can do the following in you `CategoryController`:

```php
#CategoryController
// the $category model variable is automatically injected and is a retrieved dataset from your database
public function getSubcategories(Category $category) { 

    $subcategories = $category->subcategories();

    return response()->json($subcategories->toArray());
}


Hope this can help a bit.
```

Comment: I did something but now i want to return subcategory in category nav menu please help

Comment: try to use the same route. ```Route::get('/category/subcategories/{category}', 'CategoryContoller@getSubcategories');```

Comment: OK, if you want to build a hierarchy within your view before any user interaction you will probably have a list (collection) of all your categories. You also probably already iterating over them. If so, just call the relation on the current Category-object to receive the respective subcategories: ```foreach (Categories::all() as $cat) { return $cat->subcategories(); }```

Comment: please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197408/how-to-return-subcategory-in-category-nav-menu-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment108263731_61197408

Comment: Yes, it's also ok to share the data to the view as in your other question. The solution provided there should work fine.