# How to return subcategory in category nav menu in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have used AppServiceProvider to be available for all pages and i want to load all subcategories in their own category in navigation menu now it will load all categories and in the last category it will list all subcategories that have in table please help.

[here is image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6SXS.png)

**header.blade.php**

```
 @foreach($shareData['categories'] as $category)
      <li class="dropdown m-menu-fw">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">{{ $category->name }}
                                <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>

                                @endforeach
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="m-menu-content" style="text-align: center;">
                                            <ul class="col-sm-12" >
                                                <li class="dropdown-header">{{ $category->name }}</li>
                                                @foreach($shareData['subcategories'] as $subcategory)
                                                <li><a href="#">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </ul>



                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

**AppServicePrivider.php**

```
 $categories = Category::where('status',1)->get(); 
        $subcategories = Subcategory::where('status',1)->get();
$shareData = array( 
'categories'=>$categories,
'subcategories'=>$subcategories
);

       view()->share('shareData',$shareData);
```

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';


    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function subcategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    }
}
```

Comment: Welocme to StackOverflow, Andria. Please, update your question with database structure.

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov  i did

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `with('subcategory')` directly on the Category query:

```
view()->share('shareData',Category::with('subcategory')->where('status',1)->get());
```

Then your blade view could be:

```
@foreach($shareData['categories'] as $category)
    <li class="dropdown m-menu-fw">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">{{ $category->name }}
            <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <div class="m-menu-content" style="text-align: center;">
                    <ul class="col-sm-12">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">{{ $category->name }}</li>
                        @foreach($category['subcategory'] as $subcategory)
                            <li><a href="#">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

I would change the relation method from `subcategory()` to `subcategories()`, since it is an `HasMany` relation.

Answer (score 0):

Make Your header.blade.php like this:

```
@foreach($shareData['categories'] as $category)
  <li class="dropdown m-menu-fw">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">{{ $category->name }}
                            <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>


                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                                <li>
                                    <div class="m-menu-content" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <ul class="col-sm-12" >
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">{{ $category->name }}</li>

                                            @foreach($category['subcategory'] as $subcategory)
                                            <li><a href="{{ url('/subcategory') }}/{{ $subcategory->id }}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </ul>



                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

@endforeach
```

Make your AppServiceProvider like the following code:

```
$categories = Category::where('status',1)->get(); 

$shareData = array( 
'categories'=>$categories
);

       view()->share('shareData',$shareData);
```